Unit network-manager.service not found
I installed node.js then it started removing something then I found out I couldn't access my network (wifi nor network adapter). I have tried to run different program still same.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
